# Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient in WP8

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8, blackberry-10

Actually I am trying to call HTTPS Rest Api on WP8 using XMLHTTPrequest/Ajax. I am not able to call, its always giving me failed response.

Same problem I was facing on android/ios. so I got the solution to bypass the SSL.

Could you please let us know is any way to call Untrusted HTTPS request on WP8 / Blackberry using AJAX.

Regards,
Mohammad

Comment: Did you try to import your self-signed certificate CA into phone.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data you are transferring that you would consider unverified cryptography to be adequate, perhaps you can explain. If it is user data, the BlackBerry vendor agreement requires that applications take responsible care with user data.

Comment: Hi Jdiver, I already create self-signed certificate and ran the certificate on wp8. Still its giving same problem.

Comment: I try to posting https://testmobile.xxxx.ae/getLookups and param is {"origin" : "smartphone", "text" : "complaint_text"} using Ajax. as its giving me fail response.